# Google Play console is asking for business data from my personal account

Tags: android, security, mobile, google-play-services, google-play-console

I signed up for Google Play console yesterday and paid US$25. It asked for authentication documents. I entered the photo of my official ID card and my address. Here's a response today:

Reason for failure: You submitted a document associated with individual accounts, but you are using an organizational account. Please submit one of the documents we accept for organizations or contact customer support to change your account type.

I looked at the [account details page](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/contact-details). my account is personal. What do I do now?

I'm afraid to repost because nothing has changed. My photos or other official documents are ready, but I couldn't find phone support like Apple on Google.

At first I was waiting for Google to accept this situation.

Answer (score 0):

From Google Play Console, click on the (**?**) icon in the upper right corner.

Then click on *Contact Us* and tell them about your situation.

**Note:** ***Always*** use your passport as an identification document. Google does not recognize most countries' personal IDs.

And don't worry. This happened with one of my clients recently and was resolved in one month.

[image]